# How to find all combination from multiple sets of elements?

Tags: python, combinations

I want to form all possible 6 combinations out of 3 groups of elements. The composition is as follows:

- take 2 from group A (`a,b,c,d,e`)
- take 2 from group B (`f,g,h,i,j`) and
- take 2 from group C (`k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t`)
  Also, after this, I want to export it as a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4   Column 5    Column 6
   a            b        f            g         k           l
```

and so on...

ps. it could be numbered if letters are not allowed.
I've tried using `itertools`, and list, but still nothing. I hope you could me help out.

Comment: That wouldn't give you 6 combinations, it would give you `4*5/2+4*5/2+9*10/2` combinations.

Comment: And even that, under the assumption that the order is insignificant.

Comment: @goodvibration I'd say it will even be `(4*5/2) * (4*5/2) * (9*10/2)`

Comment: @toydarian: Yup, you're right!

Comment: the total number of combination is 4,500, that is 5C2 * 5C2x * 10C2
C refers to combination.
what i'm looking for is the set of all combination comprising 6 elements. that is 
2 from group A
2 from group B, and
2 from group C
e.i. (a,b,f,g,k,l)

Comment: "6 combination" -----------> yup that's incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for your permutations:

```py
# Print CSV header
print("Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4,Column 5,Column 6")

A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
C = ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']

for a1 in range(0, len(A)):
  for a2 in range(a1 + 1, len(A)):
    
    for b1 in range(0, len(B)):
      for b2 in range(b1 + 1, len(B)):
        
        for c1 in range(0, len(C)):
          for c2 in range(c1 + 1, len(C)):
            
            print(A[a1] + "," + A[a2] + "," + B[b1] + "," + B[b2] + "," + C[c1] + "," + C[c2])
```

It will print 4500 lines for the input specified in the questions.
It assumes the order does not matter, so if `(a, b)` appears, `(b, a)` will not appear. It also does not output a letter twice `(a, a)` will not appear.

If you want to have double letters, replace `a1 + 1` with `a1` (for `b` and `c` as well).
If the order matters, (so you want to have `(a, b)` **and** `(b, a)`), replace `a1 + 1` with `0` (for `b` and `c` as well).

Comment: Finally!!!! this is awesome!!!!, i played a bit, changed how many items to take from each group(3, 2, 1) etc. and IT WORKS!!!!. PERFECTLY!!!! Thanks a lot man!!!!. One more thing, if it's not a bother, how do export it to csv file? :)

Comment: I changed the output so it will print CSV (= Comma Separated Values). It should give you an idea on how to change the output to whatever you want. When you run it, you can just pipe it to a file like this: `python3 script.py > output.csv` or if you want to write it using python itself, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), it covers the topic quite extensively.

Comment: I've Finally got it!!!!!! thanks again!!!!! i'll come back for more LOL.THANK YOU!!!!! :)

Comment: No problem! Would be nice, if you upvoted and accepted my answer ;)

Comment: Done!! :)Thanks again :)